# Setting Matlab xtick and xlabel at different intervals

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a grid of latitude and longitude at spacing of 5 degrees

```
set(gca, 'xtick', [-180:5:180]);
set(gca, 'ytick', [-90:5:90]);
```

but I am trying to get them to label at different intervals, 10 degrees
When I try to

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {'-180', '-170'... to 180})
```

Its not working and placing 2 xlabels since the xticklabel interval is twice the xtick

Answer (score 3):

You need to pad the `XTickLabel` array with blank values. It can accept numerical arrays as an input as long as `num2str` operates correctly. This accomplishes the task but there's probably a prettier way to do it:

```
% Set up a blank axis
axes
set(gca, 'ylim', [-90 90]);
set(gca, 'xlim', [-180 180]);
set(gca, 'xtick', [-180:5:180]);
set(gca, 'ytick', [-90:5:90]);

% Begin workaround
temp = cell([1,73]);

for ii = 0:36
    temp{2*ii+1} = -180 + ii*10;
end

set(gca,'XTickLabel',temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want some xticks without label, you need to name them blank. this is how you can do it.

```
%preallocating strings
xtick_names = strings(1, length(-180:5:180))
xtick_names(1:2:end) = -180:10:180
set(gca, 'xticklabels', xtick_names)
```